# I am using Log4j to send email with exception details in java programming, is it possible to get the server details?

Tags: java, exception, log4j

I would like to know how to send server information [suppose if I have 2 servers on prod environment, I want to get the hostname of that]. Is it possible to implement with log4J ? else how? kindly help

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573058/hostname-in-file-created-by-log4j

Comment: Thanks a lot it solved using MDC concept